# Getting Filename without extension : camel

Tags: file, apache-camel

I have header with filename with extension like this

`<setHeader>
<simple>Test.txt</simple>
</setHeader>`

I need to fetch only filename ie. Test alone in another header. Can anyone help me to achieve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple options. The examples take the full filename from a header and write the filename without extension into another header.

You write a Java Bean to use full Java power (for example Apache Commons FilenameUtils.getBaseName) and call it from your route. See [this Camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/parameter-binding-annotations.html) how to inject header values into your bean methods. In the route you call the bean like this

```
.setHeader("filename", method(beanReference, "methodName"))
```

Or you add camel-groovy to your dependencies to get more scripting power than with Camel Simple. Then you can do it directly in the Camel route

```
setHeader("filename").groovy("request.headers.get('fullFilename')
    .take(request.headers.get('fullFilename').lastIndexOf('.'))")
```

Comment: Burki, Can u please explain how to use groovy in Spring DSL

Comment: <setHeader headerName="filename"><groovy>"your groovy expression"</groovy></setHeader>

Comment: Hey Burki, I tried what u have mentioned, nut I'M getting error. No language could be found for: groovy even though I have camel-Script jar in workspace. Also I tried with filter in place of setHeader, getting no child node after filter error i got.

Comment: Have you added `camel-groovy` to your dependencies? Also see [here](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-groovy/src/main/docs/groovy-language.adoc) how to use Groovy in Camel

Comment: THank you Burki, **<setHeader headerName="fullFilename">
    <simple>Test.txt</simple>
   </setHeader>
   <log message="${header.fullFilename}"/>
   <setHeader headerName="filename">
    <groovy>request.headers.get('fullFilename').take(request.headers.get('fullFilename').lastIndexOf('.'))</groovy>
   </setHeader>
   <log message="${header.filename}"/>** I used above piece of code to achieved and added camel-groovy jar it worked. Thanks a lot.